# Disaster recovery process document for Google cloud Virtual Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disaster-recovery

Hello we have been directed by auditors to provide disaster recovery document for Google Cloud Virtual Machine. Please Is this provided by Google? If so how can I get it. I would appreciate resources I can use to create one for my virtual machine on Google Cloud Compute

Regards

Software Developer

Answer (score 1):

The document that you mention should be created by the person/team that designed your production. In this documentation [1] you can find some guidance in how to design your disaster recovery environment (if it is not already implemented).

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/dr-scenarios-planning-guide

Comment: Thanks for the resource Ruben